# Invalid regular expression:: Range out of order in character class

Tags: javascript, webpack, protocol-buffers, google-closure-compiler

I'm trying to use some protocol buffer code generated with `protoc` for javascript. I got some javascript files that i can import (after choosing the `commonjs` style) into other javascript files.

I've installed an npm dependency called `google-protobuf` and am able to bundle all javascript with webpack. When i try to run the page in firefox i get no errors related to this, chrome however gives me:

```
Invalid regular expression: /[Ö‘-Û¯Ûº-à£¿â€�-��-�ï¬-ï·¿ï¹°-ï»¼]/: Range out of order in character class
```

I've tried adding some additional tags to `<meta>` and `<script>` and they don't work. I've never seen an error like this and don't know where to start looking.

The end goal is, i'd like all my `npm i` and all my `import { Foo } from 'foo.js'` to work on a web page without errors.

What webpack injected using `HTMLWebpackPlugin` is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="frontseat.bundle.js"></script>
```

Originally there are no `<meta>` tags, i just added the one under head so it looks:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to update your regex to this regex below:

```
[Ö‘\-Û¯Ûº-à£¿â€�-��-�ï¬-ï·¿ï¹°-ï»¼]
```

And your meta tag is like this? `<meta charset="utf-8">` with this charset

Comment: I don't think i have control over wherever this regex is being declared. At least i'd like to keep it that way, i'd like to limit myself to `npm i google-protobuf` and not do anything else to that source file. Is there something i can do to tell webpack, the server, or the webpage that this piece of code needs to be treated differently? I can try not to bundle it together with other stuff, but i don't understand the problem.

Comment: Correct on the meta tag (although i tried others). It does absolutely nothing.

Comment: Can you show more about your tags <meta> and <script> code?

Comment: I edited the answer, but really there's nothing special about it.

Comment: Try to add this at your script tag, <script src="frontseat.bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

Comment: nope none of it work, atm the only thing i can think of trying is not bundling `google-protobuf` and trying to include that file manually with these tags.

Comment: It's very weard, you can do try it as your last option

Comment: Sounds like a problem with UTF-8

Comment: It sure does :)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue as you have.I cannot upgrade google-protobuf over than `3.6.1`. Only version 3.6.1 works for me before. All versions later 3.6.1 raise the same errors in my project.

However, the `<meta charset="utf-8">` helps now on my side. I create a minimum sample and hope it can give you some idea.

google-protobuf version: `3.11.2`

*index.js*

```
import * as pb from 'google-protobuf';
console.log(pb);
```

*build command*

```
npx webpack index.js -o bundle.js
```

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Then, you should be able to see something like this on chrome devtools console without the error.

```
{Map: ƒ, Message: ƒ, BinaryReader: ƒ, BinaryWriter: ƒ, ExtensionFieldInfo: ƒ, …}
```

Comment: It looks like adding one of these tags indeed helped, it's my caching that was turned on in chrome that was messing with it.